# What is the largest 2-digit prime factor of the integer $\binom{200}{100}$

Tags: number-theory

What is the largest 2-digit prime factor of the integer $\dbinom{200}{100}$?

Comment: Probably the reason some people have down-voted this question and some have voted to close it is that it's phrased in language appropriate for assigning homework.  Instead of just voting against it, they should explain that in a comment here. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6):

$\displaystyle\binom{200}{100}=\frac{200!}{100!~100!}$

every prime factor between 1 and 100 appears twice in the denominator.
So, we need to find a $2$–digit prime $p$ that appears three times in the numerator $200!$, or $3p< 200$.The largest such prime is $61$.

Answer (score 3):

Cute problem.

HINT: If $p$ is a prime, and $67\le p\le 100$, there are two factors of $p$ in the numerator and two factors of $p$ in the denominator of $$\binom{200}{100}=\frac{200!}{100!^2}\;.$$ What does it take to get another factor of $p$ in the numerator but *not* in the denominator?